# Failed to get images from camera DJI OSMO

Tags: ios, swift, camera, dji-sdk

I'm working with DJI sdk to get the photographs taken with the camera osmo. The problem I have is that when I show a picture on the screen gives me the following error:

```
"ERROR: fetchThumbnailWithCompletion: ErrorDomain DJISDKErrorDomainCode = -1004 =" System is busy, Please retry later (Code: -1004). ""
```

So it is written in the sdk:

```
@IBAction func onShowThumbnailButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.showThumbnailButton.enabled = false
    if self.imageMedia?.thumbnail == nil {
        // fetch thumbnail is not invoked yet

        self.imageMedia?.fetchThumbnailWithCompletion({[weak self](error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                self?.showAlertResult("ERROR: fetchThumbnailWithCompletion:\(error!.description)")
            }
            else {
                self?.showPhotoWithImage(self!.imageMedia!.thumbnail!)
            }
            self?.showThumbnailButton.enabled = true
        })
    }
}
```

But I need to show 6 images, therefore I make 6 times (6 times using a do) what is inside the IBAction. Then at that time the error occurs, because if I do it only once that error does not happen.

In addition, selecting ok error that appears like still works for other images but the idea is that no such error appears.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have switched the camera to download mode (https://developer.dji.com/iframe/mobile-sdk-doc/ios/Classes/DJICamera.html). If you have already done that, then add delay between photo shooting and download.